# React if else condition issue

Tags: reactjs

I am getting syntex error in below statement -

```
render(){
        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
                <div>{this.props.registerMessage && this.props.registerMessage.status.map((msg, idx) => { 
                        {(this.props.registerMessage.status == 100) ? (return (<span key={idx} id="succ">{this.errorMapping[msg]}</span>)) : (return (<span key={idx} id="err">{this.errorMapping[msg]}</span>))}
                    })}</div>
        </DefaultLayout>
    )
}
```

browser showing syntax error at - "`== 100) ? (return (<span`
Please let me know what I am doing wrong ?
And "Is we can store session in react.js ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if-else within a map function

```
render(){
        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
                <div>{this.props.registerMessage && this.props.registerMessage.status.map((msg, idx) => { 
                         if(msg == 100) { return <span key={idx} id="succ">{this.errorMapping[msg]}</span>
                         } else {
                              return <span key={idx} id="err">{this.errorMapping[msg]}</span>
                        }
                    })
                }</div>
        </DefaultLayout>
    )
}
```

if you use ternary operator you also need to the return the result after the expression

```
render(){
        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
                <div>{this.props.registerMessage && this.props.registerMessage.status.map((msg, idx) => { 
                       return  <div>{(this.props.registerMessage.status == 100) ?    (<span key={idx} id="succ">{this.errorMapping[msg]}</span>) : (<span key={idx} id="err">{this.errorMapping[msg]}</span>)}</div>
                    })}</div>
        </DefaultLayout>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return` from the ternary statement and add it to the beginning, removing the additional `{` and `}`:

```
return (this.props.registerMessage.status == 100) ? (<span key={idx} id="succ">{this.errorMapping[msg]}</span>) : (<span key={idx} id="err">{this.errorMapping[msg]}</span>);
```

but ideally move the statement to a function, to increase readability:

```
render() {
    const {registerMessage} = this.props;

    const renderMessage = (message, index) => {
       const id = (registerMessage.status == 100) ? "succ" : "err";

       return (
           <span key={index} id={id}>
               {this.errorMapping[msg]}
           </span>
       );
    };

    return (
        <DefaultLayout>
            <div>
                {registerMessage && registerMessage.status.map(renderMessage)}
            </div>
       </DefaultLayout>
    );
}
```

Also note that you are creating multiple components with the same `id` which will probably break the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

Sulthan is correct, this is a version with a cleaner ternary statement:

```
 render(){
    return (
        <DefaultLayout>
            <div>
                {
                    this.props.registerMessage && this.props.registerMessage.status.map((msg, idx) => { 
                        {
                            this.props.registerMessage.status == 100 
                                ? <span key={idx} id="succ">{this.errorMapping[msg]}</span> 
                                : <span key={idx} id="err">{this.errorMapping[msg]}</span>
                        }
                    })
                }
            </div>
        </DefaultLayout>
    )
}
```